# Dynamically create async function (error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to code asyncfunction but I get an error(await is only valid in async function), the question is: it's possible to do this?

```
const run_qry = require('./sequelize');

app.post('/resultdata', (req, res) => {

    const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;

    let test001 = new AsyncFunction('dat', `{
        var mySet  = new Set();
        var arrObj = [];
        
        // QUERY TO DATABASE
        let queryDB = await run_qry.query('select * from public.list_users()');
        
       // LOOP DATA
        queryDB.forEach((element, index, array) => {
            var row = [];

            row.push({vareg:  element.val, trans_id: element.id, til_scrip: 1});
            row.push({vareg:  element.val, trans_id: element.id, til_scrip: 1});
            mySet.add(row);
        });

        // NEW ARRAY
        for (let rs of mySet) {
            const objReg = new Object();

            for (let rs_child of rs) {
                objReg["col" + rs_child.vareg]           = rs_child.vareg;
                objReg["col" + rs_child.vareg + "_type"] = rs_child.til_scrip;
            };

            arrObj.push(objReg);
        };
        
        //RETURNING NEW ARRAY OBJ
        return arrObj;
    };`);
    
    test001(null).then(x => { res.send(x); });
});
```

i'm using nodejs and express, i would greatly appreciate any help or any option to do it.

ERROR:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `await` works only within in the `async` function. Change your arrow function to arrow async function.

#### change this line

```js
app.post('/resultdata', (req, res) => {
```

#### to this

```js
app.post('/resultdata', async (req, res) => {
```

Comment: thanks for helping me, i'am a beginner in javascript. now it's showing me another error: `(node:20580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: run_qry is not defined` what part is wrong?